# Kendoui How to dynamically add Kendo Angular 2 grids to a panelbar?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a panel bar with a list of panels that show correctly. The problem is I need to show a totally different grid for each panel. How can I do that?

My data structure looks like this

```
let gridData: any[] = [];

           var objectForGrid1 = {

           C1: "123456",

           C2: "1234",

           C4: "4567"

           }
```

```
var objectForGrid2 = {

          C1: "Product",

          C2: "Product Description",

          C3: "Date",

          C4: "Date"

          }

         gridData.push(objectForGrid1);

         gridData.push(objectForGrid2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [templates](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/panelbar/templates/#toc-templates) to provide different Grids with their respective settings as content for the different PanelBar items, e.g.:

```
<kendo-panelbar>
      <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="'Grid 1'" [expanded]="true">
            <ng-template kendoPanelBarContent>
              <kendo-grid [data]="grid1Data"></kendo-grid>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
        <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="'Grid 2'" [expanded]="true">
            <ng-template kendoPanelBarContent>
              <kendo-grid [data]="grid2Data"></kendo-grid>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-panelbar-item>
    </kendo-panelbar>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrQR5YJyAdgL0lNpjsTW?p=preview)

Comment: So what if I dynamically need grids? I wont know how many grids I will need until after a stored procedure is returned from a database. It could be 2 grids, it could be 10 grids to go in the panel. I wouldn't know until runtime so I need a way to add them dynamically like maybe an ngFor or something

Comment: Loop through a collection with properties for the different Grids via *ngFor and create a PanelBar item for each, e.g.:

 http://plnkr.co/edit/zHU1s8cDTovr3go3mVGi?p=preview

Comment: You are a lifesaver